# Filter List<object> for Dictionary<string,?> and Get First Key

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `IList<object>` which contains a list of `string`, `Dictionary<string, string[]>` or `Dictionary<string, object>`. I would like to get the first string of each `Dictionary`.

I've tried:

```cs
var firstStrings =
    list
    .Where(x => !(x is string))
    .Select(x => ((Dictionary<string, object>)x).Keys.ElementAt(0))
    .ToArray();
```

But I get the error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, you can't cast a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. One way to do what you want is to cast to `IDictionary` (and use `OfType` instead of the `Where` clause for better type safety:

```
var firstStrings =
    list.OfType<IDictionary>()
        .Select(x => x.Keys
                      .OfType<object>()
                      .First()
                      .ToString()
               )
        .ToArray();
```

You may need to add `using System.Collections;` to your using block since `IDictionary` is in a different namespace than the generic class.

One other note - dictionaries are not ordered, so the "first" element is arbitrary (adding a new key/value pair may change the "first" key you get back).

Comment: I can't get this to compile is says `IDictionary` requires 2 type arguments.

Comment: In my use case the dictionary should only have a single key value pair in it. But good tip nonetheless!

Comment: I'm getting the error `ICollection` does not contain a definition `ElementAt`. I could probably figure that part out myself. But just thought you should know.

Comment: I think you will need to use `Cast<string>` in the keys collection before you can use first

Comment: `x.Keys.First()` `ICollection` doesn't contain `First`

Comment: The only risk with `x.Keys.OfType<string>()` is if for some reason you had a dictionary that did not use `string` as the key type, this would blow up at runtime.

Comment: @Jon49 Ahh ok I forgot `First()` doesn't work on non-generic interfaces. `OfType` will convert it for you. I'll update the answer.